# Ive got a wierd blue tint

Tags: texture-painting

I'm trying to make a runic rock but after the texture paint, the main rock with the runes has a blue tint. I like it but I would like to get rid of it, could you help me with removing it? I'm guessing it a problem with the image I used as a factor because it's saying it's being used by tow different object but I don't really know. Sorry for the really low amount of samples, I got it from the 3d viewport rendered view.[image: The rock]

Comment: It looks like you're using an emission shader, and the rock is just reflecting the light from that.

Comment: No, if you look closely, the other rocks don't seem to be having that problem. Good point though I'm just gonna check and come back

Comment: no, the blue tint is still there

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Wait, I fixed the problem thanks to your advice. It had a tint because my mat mask was not completely black and because white was interpreted as the blue emission, so as mine was a really dark grey like 3 mm off the bottom of black, there was a blue tint. Thanks your help man.

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: i tried but blend-exchange didnt work

Comment: Plus, i fixed it, th details are above in case anyone needs it. If you know anyone with this problem, pls send it to them

Comment: Good to hear! You can post and then accept the solution in the answer section and it'll help surface it in Google results.